# Visual Studio 2010 XAML layout editor not WYSIWYG

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

When I'm creating WPF layouts in Visual Studio 2010 I just drag and drop controls from the Toolbox onto the default element, typically a Grid.   When I do this the spacing shown in Visual studio does not match what's displayed at runtime.  For example, here are the visual editor and runtime results, respectively, for two layouts . . .

[image: editor]

[image: runtime]

. . . and . . .

[image: editor]

[image: runtime]

... notice the spacing is altered.
Here's the XAML that was generated for the two examples . . .

```
  <Button Content="ProjectPattern" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,296,0,0" Name="butProjPattern" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" Click="butProjPattern_Click" />
    <TextBlock Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,0,0,141" Name="ResultProjPattern" Text="(result)"       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="41" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,295,0,0" Name="TextBlockPattern" Text="     (pattern file)" Padding="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Background="#FFF1F3FF" /> 
    <Button Content="...browse" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,294,814,0" Name="buttonPatternBrowse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Click="buttonPatternBrowse_Click" />
```

...and...

```
<Button Content="Display Cross" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="622,108,0,0" Name="buttonCross" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" Click="buttonCross_Click" />
<TextBlock Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,107,344,0" Name="ResultCross" Text="(result)" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
<Button Content="Display Diamond" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="622,138,0,0" Name="butDiamond" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" Click="butDiamond_Click" />
<TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,138,344,0" Name="ResultDiamond" Text="(result)" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
<Button Content="DisplayFullField" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="622,165,0,0" Name="butFullField" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" />
<TextBlock Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,164,344,0" Name="ResultFullField" Text="(result)" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
```

I added button handlers, text content, etc, but the layout is strictly what was generated by the Visual Studio layout editor.    One thing I noticed is that even though it's drag-and-drop from the Toolbox onto the Grid, Visual Studio is inconsistent about whether it chooses "Left" or "Right" for its HorizontalAlignment for different elements.

The container element is just a default Grid in a default Window - it can minimize but not resize . . .

```
<Window x:Class="Caller1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="1200" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid Height="460">
```

The result is that I have to waste lots of time going between the editor and running my app to "tweak" my layout.   What prevents the "WYSIWYG" layout editor from matching the runtime layout and how can I get them to correspond?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to post the xaml for the parent container too (that is, the Grid).

Comment: OK, I added that info but it's pretty basic and default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see your images (dumb work firewall), but I can tell by your XAML that you are using the `Grid` wrong. I understand that this may be the fault of the editor, but seriously, you shouldn't be setting the `Width` and `Height` properties on all your elements.

If you want a fixed size for the `Grid`'s children, set up some `RowDefinition`s and `ColumnDefinition`s and set those sizes. Your layout is much easier to work with (and will probably be more accurate in the designer) if you do this. So, your first `Grid` would look like this:

```
<Grid Margin="12,0,0,0">  
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="117" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="138" /> <!-- This is your desired width + horizontal margins -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button x:Name="butProjPattern" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Content="ProjectPattern" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Click="butProjPattern_Click" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="ResultProjPattern" 
             Grid.Column="1" 
             Margin="6,0,0,0" 
             Text="(result)" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPattern" 
             Grid.Column="2"
             Margin="3,0,0,0" 
             Padding="4"
             Text="     (pattern file)" 
             Background="#FFF1F3FF" /> 
  <Button x:Name="buttonPatternBrowse" 
          Grid.Column="3"
          Content="...browse" 
          Margin="22,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Padding="2,1"
          Click="buttonPatternBrowse_Click"  />
</Grid>
```

The other thing I want to note is that after I put this in [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/), which is great for rapid prototyping of your XAML layouts, I noticed that you should really just be using a `StackPanel`. The first grid could really be this much simpler implementation (you will have to set the `Width` on a couple of your items to match the layout):

```
<StackPanel Margin="12,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">  
  <Button x:Name="butProjPattern" 
          Content="ProjectPattern" 
          Width="117"
          Click="butProjPattern_Click" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="ResultProjPattern" 
             Margin="6,0,0,0" 
             Text="(result)" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPattern" 
             Margin="3,0,0,0" 
             Padding="4"
             Width="135"
             Text="     (pattern file)" 
             Background="#FFF1F3FF" /> 
  <Button x:Name="buttonPatternBrowse" 
          Content="...browse" 
          Margin="22,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Padding="2,1"
          Click="buttonPatternBrowse_Click"  />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Nice answer. I don't think the question includes enough information to be sure, but the lack of column/row definitions seems likely to be part of the problem!

Comment: @Abe Heidebrecht When I've hand-coded my XAML I've always used column and row definitions so **I should have thought of/noticed that**.    The examples I showed were part of a much larger layout of controls (it's a huge control panel used to test/display and industrial process) so the convenience of being able to drag and drop items was important, especially because it's likely to be touched by some people who don't know XAML very well.   Is there a way to do column and row definitions in the visual editor without hand-editing the XAML?

Comment: @user316117 I'm pretty sure you can create them in the VS designer, but honestly I've never used it. If you can upgrade to VS2012, it comes with Expression Blend, which definitely has a better WYSIWYG experience. If you're unable to upgrade, there used to be a standalone Blend, but I'm not sure you can still get it... On the other hand, it looks like you can get Blend in VS Express, so you could always download that (its free!)

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is *not* directly an answer to your actual question, but instead a suggestion to avoid your problem.

You will often get UI control placement problems when you use exact control positioning with the `Margin` property. It is a good procedure (and in WPF especially) to allow controls to place and/or space themselves using the various `Alignment` options available. I have always managed to get the desired layout using this method.

For example, had you used a `Grid` or `StackPanel` to arrange your controls, you would not have come across this problem. Many WPF developers that I know don't even bother using the designer in Visual Studio because of the problems that you mentioned... after dragging and dropping a control and then going to the XAML to remove unwanted values, it often works out quicker to simply type the XAML myself.

If you *really* want to know why the Visual Studio designer... well, er... doesn't work properly, you *may* have more luck asking on the [Microsoft Developer Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=visualstudiogeneral&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc), where you question might actually get seen by a Microsoft employee.